# Laravel 5 error when using whereIn

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I migrated my laravel app from 4 to 5 and i am having an issue with this query:

```
$ids = AssetCustomTag::whereIn('custom_tag_id', $custom)->lists('asset_id')->all();
```

where $custom is an array of ids.

The error thrown from laravel is this one.

```
Declaration of AssetCustomTag::create(array $input) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes = Array)
```

Not sure what that means as I am very new to laravel.

This is the create method. What do i need to do to it?

```
public static function create(array $input)
{
    $name = $input['name'];
    $account_id = $input['account_id'];
    ...
    ....
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you wrote a `create()` method in your `AssetCustomTag` model? That's where your error is coming from. Maybe post that?

Comment: Why would the create method even be called in there?

Comment: It probably isn't getting called. PHP strict standards are requiring that you make your method signature compatible with the parent class nonetheless.

Comment: See here for a quick example: https://3v4l.org/DI6ia. Notice I'm never calling the `foo()` method, but PHP is complaining anyway.

Comment: I just added create method, how show i implement it?

Comment: You probably don't want to add your own `create()` method at all. Typically not needed. You likely need to rethink your whole approach, update your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I fixed it. `public static function create(array $input = [])` did the trick

Comment: Yes, you made the signature match. That will get rid of this specific error, but you're setting yourself for other problems. Go read through the Eloquent docs, looks at the examples, I don't think you want your own `create` method, rarely a good idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124468/discussion-between-leon-and-jszobody).